# True-way solution in Java: parse 2 numbers from 2 strings and then return their sum

Tags: java, parsing, exception

Given the code:

```
public static int sum(String a, String b) /* throws? WHAT? */ {
  int x = Integer.parseInt(a); // throws NumberFormatException
  int y = Integer.parseInt(b); // throws NumberFormatException
  return x + y;
}
```

Could you tell if it's good Java or not? What I'm talking about is, `NumberFormatException` is an unchecked exception. You **don't have** to specify it as part of `sum()` signature. Moreover, as far as I understand, the idea of unchecked exceptions is just to signal that program's implementation is incorrect, and even more, catching unchecked exceptions is a bad idea, since it's like *fixing bad program at runtime*.

Would somebody please clarify whether:

1. I should specify `NumberFormatException` as a part of method's signature.
2. I should define my own checked exception (`BadDataException`), handle `NumberFormatException` inside the method and re-throw it as `BadDataException`.
3. I should define my own checked exception (`BadDataException`), validate both strings some way like regular expressions and throw my `BadDataException` if it doesn't match.
4. Your idea?

**Update**:

Imagine, it's not an open-source framework, that you should use for some reason. You look at method's signature and think - "OK, it never throws". Then, some day, you got an exception. Is it normal?

**Update 2**:

There are some comments saying my `sum(String, String)` is a bad design. I do absolutely agree, but for those who believe that original problem would just never appear if we had good design, here's an extra question:

The problem definition is like this: you have a data source where numbers are stored as `String`s. This source may be XML file, web page, desktop window with 2 edit boxes, whatever.

Your goal is to implement the logic that takes these 2 `String`s, converts them to `int`s and displays message box saying "the sum is xxx".

No matter what's the approach you use to design/implement this, you'll *have these 2 points of inner functionality*:

1. A place where you convert `String` to `int`
2. A place where you add 2 `int`s

The primary question of my original post is:

`Integer.parseInt()` expects *correct* string to be passed. Whenever you pass a *bad string*, it means that *your program* is incorrect (not "*your user* is an idiot"). You need to implement the piece of code where on one hand you have Integer.parseInt() with *MUST semantics* and on the other hand you need to be OK with the cases when input is incorrect - *SHOULD semantics*.

So, briefly: how do I implement *SHOULD semantics* if I only have *MUST libraries*.

Comment: That's by no means a stupid question. Actually it's a pretty good one! I'm not completely sure, which option I would choose.

Comment: To your update: Yes, according the the fail-fast principle this wouldn't necessarily be a bad thing either.

Comment: I agree with martin. It's one of the aspects of Java programming which is the least understood which requires some best practises. This can be seen by the lack of pages on the subject with very few besides O'Reilly saying "this is how it should be done".

Comment: Actually, this is an excellent question.

Comment: Great question! Also raised some great answers :D

Comment: Moreover, what I believe is that we should catch all the unchecked exceptions and inform the user about the wrong or incompatible inputs.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is a good question. I wish more people would think about such things.

IMHO, throwing unchecked exceptions is acceptable if you've been passed rubbish parameters.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't throw `BadDataException` because you shouldn't use Exceptions to control program flow. Exceptions are for the exceptional. Callers to your method can know *before* they call it if their strings are numbers or not, so passing rubbish in is avoidable and therefore can be considered a *programming error*, which means it's OK to throw unchecked exceptions.

Regarding declaring `throws NumberFormatException` - this is not that useful, because few will notice due to NumberFormatException being unchecked. However, IDE's can make use of it and offer to wrap in `try/catch` correctly. A good option is to use javadoc as well, eg:

```
/**
 * Adds two string numbers
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @return
 * @throws NumberFormatException if either of a or b is not an integer
 */
public static int sum(String a, String b) throws NumberFormatException {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(a); 
    int y = Integer.parseInt(b); 
    return x + y;
}
```

**EDITED**:
The commenters have made valid points. You need to consider how this will be used and the overall design of your app.

If the method will be used all over the place, and it's important that all callers handle problems, the declare the method as throwing a checked exception (forcing callers to deal with problems), but cluttering the code with `try/catch` blocks.

If on the other hand we are using this method with data we trust, then declare it as above, because it is not expected to ever explode and you avoid the code clutter of essentially unnecessary `try/catch` blocks.

Comment: The problem is that unchecked exceptions are often ignored and may percolate up your call stack, wreaking havoc in parts of your app that have no idea what lies beneath. The question is really which bit of code should check whether the input is valid or not.

Comment: My belief is that it's better to make a stable design that allows for programming errors, than thinking that everything should be perfect and otherwise the programmer has himself to blame.

Comment: @G_H has a point. The Java tutorials says this: "If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception". The question is where should a `RuntimeException` be handled? Should it be the caller or should the Exception be left to float up? If so how should it be handled?

Comment: To partially answer this there's two approaches I've seen: the first is to intercept `Exceptions` from lower layers and wrap them in higher level Exceptions which are more meaningful to the end user and the second is to use an uncaught exception handler which can be initialized in the application launcher.

Comment: IMHO having the NumberFormatException in the javaDoc is **much** more important. Putting it in the `throws` clause is a nice addition, but not required.

Comment: To *"Callers to your method can know before they call it if their strings are numbers or not, so passing rubbish in is avoidable"*: That's not really true. The only simple way to verify that a string parses as int is to try it out. Although you may want to do some upfront checks, exact checking is quite a PITA.

Comment: @Dorus Using javaDoc offers a false sense of security, since you would have to put it manually in the doc of every function which calls the original function. Keeping things in sync is hopeless for your own code and impossible for 3rd party code. The point is you cannot tell whether a function throws an unchecked exception or not.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I don't think you have to propagate the javadoc warning back up the method stack, because calling such a method is an implementation choice, which a method is free to change as long as its contract is upheld

Answer (score 48):

In my opinion it would be preferable to handle exception logic as far up as possible. Hence I would prefer the signature

```
 public static int sum(int a, int b);
```

With your method signature I would **not** change anything. Either you are

- Programmatically using incorrect values, where you instead could validate your producer algorithm
- or sending values from e.g., user input, in which case that module should perform the validation

Hence, exception handling in this case becomes a *documentation* issue.

Comment: I like this.  It forces the user to follow the contract, and makes the method do only one thing.

Comment: I don't understand how the usage of this method is any different than the user doing a+b. Why do we need this method?

Comment: @Swati: I think it's an _example_ , which is a great technique to show things simply. The sum method could as well be myVeryComplicatedMethodWhichComputesPhoneNumberOfMyIdealMatchGirl(int myID, int myLifeExpectancy)...

Comment: Totally agree here. a `sum` function that expects two numbers, should get two numbers. The way you got those is not related to the `sum` function. _Separate your logic correctly_. So, I'd relate this to a design issue.

Answer (score 5):

Number 4.  As given, this method should not take strings as parameters it should take integers.  In which case (since java wraps instead of overflowing) there's no possibility of an exception.

```
 x = sum(Integer.parseInt(a), Integer.parseInt(b))
```

is a lot clearer as to what is meant than 
     `x = sum(a, b)`

You want the exception to happen as close to the source (input) as possible.

As to options 1-3, you don't define an exception because you expect your callers to assume that otherwise your code can't fail, you define an exception to define what happens under known failure conditions WHICH ARE UNIQUE TO YOUR METHOD. I.e. if you have a method that is a wrapper around another object, and it throws an exception then pass it along.  Only if the exception is unique to your method should you throw a custom exception (frex, in your example, if sum was supposed to only return positive results, then checking for that and throwing an exception would be appropriate, if on the other hand java threw an overflow exception instead of wrapping, then you would pass that along, not define it in your signature, rename it, or eat it).

Update in response to update of the question:

> So, briefly: how do I implement SHOULD semantics if I only have MUST libraries.

The solution to this is to to wrap the MUST library, and return a SHOULD value.  In this case, a function that returns an Integer.  Write a function that takes a string and returns an Integer object -- either it works, or it returns null (like guava's Ints.tryParse).  Do your validation seperate from your operation, your operation should take ints.  Whether your operation gets called with default values when you have invalid input, or you do something else, will depend upon your specs -- most I can say about that, is that it's really unlikely that the place to make that decision is in the operation method.

Comment: What's your idea here? I gonna get the same issue even if I have `sum(int, int)` and `parseIntFromString(String)`. To get the same functionality, in either case, I'll have to write a piece of code where there are 2 calls to `parseIntFromString()` and 1 call to `sum()`. Consider this case, if it makes sense for you - I see no difference from the original problem's standpoint.

Comment: @loki2302: the point is the caller then gets to decide what behavior is appropriate when it's not a number.  Also, if they don't do error checking then the failure occurs one step closer to where the value is assigned -- for debugging purposes, the closer to the assignment, the easier the debugging.  And you're more likely to miss writing the appropriate unit test for the caller if you're doing TDD.  Basically you don't want to have a string supplied in method x that is supposed to be a number and then 5 classes and 20 method calls latter throw an exception when you try to treat it a number.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you trying to say that providing an interface of `int sum(String, String)` is never possible in reality?

Comment: @loki2302: Given the code shown, it'd be possible but a bad idea. If the number in the string might be a word where "2", "two", "dos", "deux", "zwo" were all to be treated the same, then that signature would be appropriate.  But as it is, the method is given two strings and treats them as integers.  Why would you ever want to do that?  It's a bad idea.

Comment: Ok, imagine a class like `TheNumber` with ctor `TheNumber(String)` and method `getIntValue()`. Then sum method is now `TheNumber sum(TheNumber, TheNumber)`. It's more or less fine design. Then imagine, you have a socket-based connection. There's a code where endpoint sends you a packet like a string "sum,123,456". You parse it and get an AST where "sum" is a root and both 123 and 456 are children. All of them are still strings, but it's a tree. So, 3 facts: `tree.root` is a word "sum", `tree.root.child[0]` is "123" and `tree.root.child[1]` is "456". How do you join this tree and `sum`? :-)

Comment: @loki2302, well given that signature I'd do whatever I was supposed to do with invalid input.  The string should probably be sum(new TheNumber("123"), new TheNumber("456")) .  If I had an implicit conversion from string to TheNumber, then I'd be calling TheNumber and it would do whatever it was supposed which would be of no concern to sum.  In no case would sum be called with strings which would be treated as a number.  If you want to do that, then use a dynamically typed language, where "zz" + 5 is perfectly valid.  I recommend perl.

Comment: Consider your `sum(new TheNumber("123"), new TheNumber("456"))`. What's the signature of `TheNumber`'s `(String)` ctor?

Comment: @loki2302: `public TheNumber(string orderCakeIfNotNumber)`. TheNumber does something special when not given a number or when given specific numbers, that's why you're using it instead of integer.parseInt.  The code given for sum OTOH deals strictly with the values *as* numbers.  You don't treat "x" as 42, or "help" as 911 or deal with really large integers.  As long as their's no logic in the method to deal with non-integer values, you shouldn't accept strings as the input.  That's why I said TheNumber would do whatever it was supposed to do with it's input, which was no concern of sum.

Comment: @loki2302: You accepted the answer saying it was ok to throw an unchecked exception when passed rubbish, but the point of a strongly typed language is to PREVENT rubbish from being passed.  Having a method that expects a string to always be an integer value is just asking for trouble.  Even Integer.parseInt doesn't deal with that well (an exception on what SHOULD be expected input is bad, .Net's integer.TryParse method is much better, although Java's lack of an out parameter makes it somewhat impractical).

Answer (score 3):

> 1. I should specify NumberFormatException as a part of method's signature.

I think so. It's a nice documentation.

> 2. I should define my own checked exception (BadDataException), handle NumberFormatException inside the method and re-throw it as BadDataException.

Sometimes yes. The checked exceptions are consider to be better in some cases, but working with them is quite a PITA. That's why many frameworks (e.g., Hibernate) use runtime exceptions only.

> 3. I should define my own checked exception (BadDataException), validate both strings some way like regular expressions and throw my BadDataException if it doesn't match.

Never. More work, less speed (unless you expect throwing the exception to be a rule), and no gain at all.

> 4. Your idea?

None at all.

Answer (score 2):

Nr 4.

I think I wouldn't change the method at all.
I would put a try catch around the calling method or higher in the stack-trace where I'm in a context where I can gracefully recover with business logic from the exception.

I wouldn't certainty do #3 as I deem it overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that what you are writing is going to be consumed (like as an API) by someone else, then you should go with 1, NumberFormatException is specifically for the purpose of communicating such exceptions and should be used.

Answer (score 2):

1. First you need to ask your self, does the user of my method needs to worry about entering wrong data, or is it expected of him to enter proper data (in this case String).
   This expectation is also know as design by [contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).
2. and 3.  Yes you probably should define BadDataException or even better use some of the excising ones like NumberFormatException but rather the leaving the standard message to be show. Catch NumberFormatException in the method and re-throw it with your message, not forgetting to include the original stack trace.
3. It depends on the situation bu I would probably go with re-throwing NumberFormatException with some additional info. And also there must be a javadoc explanation of what are the expected values for `String a, String b`

Answer (score 1):

Depends a lot on the scenario you are in.

Case 1. Its always you who debug the code and no one else and exception wont cause a bad user experience

Throw the default NumberFormatException

Case2: Code should be extremely maintainable and understandable

Define your own exception and add lot more data for debugging while throwing it.

You dont need regex checks as, its gonna go to exception on bad input anyway.

If it was a production level code, my idea would be to define more than one custom exceptions, like

1. Number format exception
2. Overflow exception
3. Null exception etc...

and deal with all these seperately

Answer (score 1):

1. You may do so, to make it clear that this can happen for incorrect input. It might help someone using your code to remember handling this situation. More specifically, you're making it clear that you don't handle it in the code yourself, or return some specific value instead. Of course, the JavaDoc should make this clear too.
2. Only if you want to force the caller to deal with a checked exception.
3. That seems like overkill. Rely on the parsing to detect bad input.

Overal, a NumberFormaException is unchecked because it is expected that correctly parseable input is provided. Input validation is something you should handle. However, actually parsing the input is the easiest way to do this. You could simply leave your method as it is and warn in the documentation that correct input is expected and anyone calling your function should validate both inputs before using it.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the answer that the runtime exception should be allowed to be percolated, from a design and usability perspective, it would be a good idea to wrap it into a IllegalArgumentException rather than throw it as NumberFormatException. This then makes the contract of your method more clear whereby it declares an illegal argument was passed to it due to which it threw an exception.

Regarding the update to the question "Imagine, it's not an open-source framework, that you should use for some reason. You look at method's signature and think - "OK, it never throws". Then, some day, you got an exception. Is it normal?" the javadoc of your method should always spill out the behavior of your method (pre and post constraints). Think on the lines of say collection interfaces where in if a null is not allowed the javadoc says that a null pointer exception will be thrown although it is never part of the method signature.

Comment: NumberFormatException is a subclass of IllegalArgumentException, so this wrapping adds no information.

Comment: what it means that the exception can be percolated as it is (as in this case nfe is already an illegal argument exception) and there can be a generic handling to deal with illegal arguments somewhere up in the call hierarchy. so if this was an example where the arguments were passed by the user, there could be a generic code which would wrap all the handling for illegal arguments and inform the user about it.

Answer (score 1):

Any exceptional behaviour should be clarified in the documentation. Either it should state that this method returns a special value in case the of failure (like `null`, by changing the return type to `Integer`) or case 1 should be used. Having it explicit in the method's signature lets the user ignore it if he ensures correct strings by other means, but it still is obvious that the method doesn't handle this kind of failure by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your updated question.

Yes it's perfectly normal to get "surprise" exceptions.
Think about all the run time errors one got when new to programming.

```
e.g ArrayIndexOutofBound
```

Also a common surprise exception from the for each loop.

```
ConcurrentModificationException or something like that
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are talking about good java practice ,in my opinion it is always better

- To handle the unchecked exception then analyze it and through  a custom unchecked exception.
- Also while throwing custom unchecked exception you can add the Exception message that your client could understand and also print the stack trace of original exception
- No need to declare custom exception as "throws" as it is unchecked one.
- This way you are not violating the use of what unchecked exceptions are made for, at the same time client of the code would easily understand the reason and solution for the exception .
- Also documenting properly in java-doc is a good practice and helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your purpose, but I would document it at a minimum:

```
/**
 * @return the sum (as an int) of the two strings
 * @throws NumberFormatException if either string can't be converted to an Integer
 */
public static int sum(String a, String b)
  int x = Integer.parseInt(a);
  int y = Integer.parseInt(b);
  return x + y;
}
```

Or, take a page from the Java source code for the java.lang.Integer class:

```
public static int parseInt(java.lang.String string) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of interesting answers to this question. But I still want to add this :

For string parsing, I always prefer to use "regular expressions". The java.util.regex package is there to help us. So I will end up with something like this, that never throws any exception. It's up to me to return a special value if I want to catch some error :

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public static int sum(String a, String b) {
  final String REGEX = "\\d"; // a single digit
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(a);
  if (matcher.find()) { x = Integer.matcher.group(); }
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(b);
  if (matcher.find()) { y = Integer.matcher.group(); }
  return x + y;
}
```

As one can see, the code is just a bit longer, but we can handle what we want (and set default values for x and y, control what happens with else clauses, etc...) 
We could even write a more general transformation routine, to which we can pass strings, defaut return values, REGEX code to compile, error messages to throw, ...

Hope It was usefull.

Warning : I was not able to test this code, so please excuse eventual syntax problems.

Comment: are we speaking about Java? What is `Integer.matcher`? `private` variable inside method? Missing `()` for ifs, missing lots of `;`, `x`,`y` not declared, `matcher` declared twice, ...

Comment: Indeed Carlos, I did it in a hurry, and as I said, was not able to test it immediately. Sorry. I wanted to show the regex way of doing.

Comment: OK, but this does not solve the issue with NumberFormatException - the main question IMO - (assuming that `Integer.matcher.group()` is meant to be `Integer.parseInt(matcher.group())`)

Answer (score 1):

How about the input validation pattern implemented by [Google's 'Guava' library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or [Apache's 'Validator' library](http://commons.apache.org/validator/) ([comparison](http://piotrjagielski.com/blog/google-guava-vs-apache-commons-for-argument-validation/))?

In my experience, it is considered good practice to validate a function's parameters at the beginning of the function and throw Exceptions where appropriate.

Also, I would consider this question to be largely language independent. The 'good practice' here would apply to all languages that have functions which can take parameters which may or may not be valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think your very first sentence of "Quite a stupid question" is very relevant. Why would you ever write a method with that signature in the first place? Does it even make sense to sum two strings? If the calling method wants to sum two strings, it is the calling method's responsibility to make sure they are valid ints and to convert them before calling the method.

In this example, if the calling method cannot convert the two Strings into an int, it could do several things. It really depends at what layer this summation occurs at. I am assuming the String conversion would be very close to front-end code (if it was done properly), such that case 1. would be the most likely:

1. Set an error message and stop processing or redirect to an error page
2. Return false (ie, it would put the sum into some other object and would not be required to return it)
3. Throw some BadDataException as you are suggesting, but unless the summation of these two numbers is very important, this is overkill, and like mentioned above, this is probably bad design since it implies that the conversion is being done in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

You face this issue because you let user errors propagate too deep into the core of the application and partly also because you abuse Java data types.

You should have a clearer separation between user input validation and business logic, use proper data typing, and this problem will disappear by itself.

The fact is the semantics of `Integer.parseInt()` are known - it's primary purpose it to parse *valid* integers. You're missing an explicit user input validation/parsing step.